# Understanding types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I am trying to map a function, h, to a list of primes. Both are given below:

```
f k x = floor ( log k / log x )

h = f 20

primes = 2 : sieve [3,5..]
  where
    sieve (p:xs) = p:[ x | x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0 ]
```

However when I try `map h primes` I get the following error:

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
  (Enum a0)
    arising from the arithmetic sequence `3, 5 .. '
```

and so on...

Both the function f and primes seem to work as expected but I cannot apply f to the numbers in primes??? What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Ah, don't edit the question to a new form after it's answered. You can ask a new one. :)

Comment: Ah rite, sorry. Shall I revert my edit and create a new question?

Comment: Don't revert it. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `primes` is of type `[Integer]`.

Your function `h` is of type `Double -> Integer`.

The type of `map` is like this:

```
ghci> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Or when specialized to a list of `Integer` it's type signatures becomes:

```
map :: (Integer -> b) -> [Integer] -> [b]
```

But your `h` function which you are passing to `map` is of type `Double -> Integer` and hence it doesn't typecheck because it is expecting something of `Integer -> b` and not a function accepting `Double`.

Always try to write type signature before function, that will make your life easier.

Comment: Sorry, I mad a mistake in posting the question. I am actually applying  `h = f 20` and getting the above error. Have updated question.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

`primes :: Integral a => [a]` and `h :: (RealFrac a, Integral b, Floating a) => a -> b`. Now, there aren't any types that are instances of both `RealFrac` and `Integral` but GHC doesn't know this, so the error message it gives is a bit confusing.

### The reason

`log :: Floating a => a -> a`, `(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a` and `floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`, so when we compose them we get the above type signature. Haskell has strong number types and this means that there are no implicit conversions between integer and floating point types.

### The solution

Use the explicit conversion function `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`:

```
map (h . fromIntegral) primes
```

Answer (score 0):

What type does `primes` have? That completely depends on the circumstances. It could be

```
primes :: [Integer]
```

or something else. It isn't clear, since literals like `3` have the type `3 :: Num a => a`. The only thing we can be sure about, is that whatever it is need to be an instance of `Enum`, otherwise `[3,5..]` couldn't work.

Now what's the type of `f`? `f` uses `log` on it's arguments, and then floors the result, so we can expect something like

```
f :: (RealFrac a, Floating a, Integral b) => a -> a -> b
```

However, this already hints that you cannot use it with `map`, since `map` expects `(a -> b)` as first parameter. And more important, the elements of `primes` don't fulfill the `Floating` constraint:

```
*Main> let (p1:p2:_) = primes
*Main> f p1 p2

<interactive>:29:1:
    No instance for (RealFrac Integer) arising from a use of `f'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Integer)
    In the expression: f p1 p2
    In an equation for `it': it = f p1 p2
```

So we either need to change `primes` type or `f`'s type. We change `f`'s type:

```
f k x = floor ( log (fromIntegral k) / log (fromIntegral x) )
```

Now we can use `f p1 p2` as expected:

```
*Main> let (p1:p2:_) = primes
*Main> f p1 p2
0
```

But what about the `map` issue? `map` expects `(a -> b)` as first parameter, and `f` is still `(a -> b -> c)`*. From your current code it seems like you would like to use two consecutive primes and apply `f`. For this, we first use `uncurry`:

```
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
```

Now `uncurry f` has `(a, b) -> c`. But now the list (`primes`) isn't a list of pairs. However, we can fix this easily, we `zip` primes with its tail:

```
map (uncurry f) (zip primes $ tail primes)
```

And that's how you can map a function with two parameters on consecutive elements of a single list.

---

<sub>*k or x could be of different Integral types</sub>